# Steam / DirectX

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, directx-12

While I was playing Counter Strike: Global Offensive, I got kicked from the game. The reason I got kicked is that Steam displayed me VAC ban warning. They told me to verify CS:GO game files which I did. And every time I verify after around 2 hours I can play game (competitive or wingman) and again same thing happens. Every time I got "VAC BAN WARNING" when I verify, I got feedback that 1 or 2 files are missing when I start the game. Every time Microsoft DirectX is updating or installing every single time. I tried all Reinstall Steam/CSGO, updated windows, watched Youtube clips but nothing. So my guess is that Microsoft DirectX is somehow guilty but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your anti-virus. Perhaps it gave a false-positive to a DirectX file and quarantined the file, if it didn't just remove it. Afterwards, add the CS:GO folder as an exception in your anti-virus so it doesn't happen again.